# SQL: UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Update the emp table, move the employee with the highest commission to department number 40, make him/her a manager and give him/her a pay raise of £1000. Hint : Use a subquery and >= all as with the ALL and ANY slide on the SQL Commands Handout.

All I seem to get:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You should edit your question and include your queries.

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Screenshots are evil. Copy/paste the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is:

```
update emp
    set . . .
    where comm = max(comm);
```

The error is correct for several reasons.  The simplest is that aggregation functions do not belong in a `where` clause; nor do they belong in an update.

If you want to update *one* row, you would do:

```
update emp
    set . . .
    order by comm desc
    limit 1;
```

If you want to update *all* rows where `comm` is maximum (and there could be multiple such rows), then use `join`:

```
update emp e join
       (select max(comm) as maxcomm from emp) ee
       on e.comm = ee.maxcomm
    set . . .;
```

I should note that neither of these are standard SQL.  The standard SQL method (which MySQL does not support) is:

```
update emp
    set . . .
    where comm = (select max(e2.comm) from emp e2);
```

Comment: Thanks mate it helped